# Joining a derived table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, derived

I have 4 tables:

- Competencies: a list of obviously competencies, static and a library
- Competency Levels: refers to an associated group of competencies and has a number of competencies I am testing for
- call_competency: a list of all 'calls' that have recorded the specified competency
- competency_review_status: proving whether each call_competency was reviewed

Now I am trying to write this query to count a total and spit out the competency, id and whether a user has reached the limit. Everything works except for when I add the user. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, once I limit call competency by user in the where clause, I get a small subset that ONLY exists in call_competency returned when I want the entire list of competencies.

The competencies not reached should be false, ones recorded appropriate number true. A FULL list from the competency table.

I added the derived table, not sure if this is right, obviously it doesn't run properly, not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm wasting time. Any help much appreciated.

```
SELECT comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description,
       CASE WHEN sum(CASE WHEN crs.grade = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN crs.grade = 'Fail' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END END) >= comp_l.competency_break_level
       THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
FROM competencies comp
INNER JOIN competency_levels comp_l  ON comp_l.competency_group = comp.competency_group
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT competency_id 
  FROM call_competency
  WHERE call_competency.user_id IN (
    SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE email= _studentemail
  )
) call_c ON call_c.competency_id = comp.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN competency_review_status crs ON crs.id = call_competency.review_status_id
GROUP BY comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description, comp_l.competency_break_level
ORDER BY comp.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Shooting from the hip, no installation to test)

It looks like the below should do the trick. You apparently had some of the joins mixed up, with a column from a relation that was not referenced. Also, the `CASE` statement in the main query could be much cleaner.

```
SELECT comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description,
       (sum(CASE WHEN crs.grade = 'Pass' THEN 1 WHEN crs.grade = 'Fail' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) >= comp_l.competency_break_level) AS reached_limit
FROM competencies comp
JOIN competency_levels comp_l USING (competency_group)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT competency_id, review_status_id
  FROM call_competency
  JOIN users ON id = user_id
  WHERE email = _studentemail
) call_c ON call_c.competency_id = comp.id
LEFT JOIN competency_review_status crs ON crs.id = call_c.review_status_id
GROUP BY comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description
ORDER BY comp.id;
```

Comment: beauty. I had to add comp_l.competency_break_level to the group by, but otherwise it works. Thanks for the tips on refactoring and all your help, works wonderfully.